# Conditional COPY based on ARG value Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

So I have following ARG:

```
ARG BRANCH_NAME
ENV BRANCH_NAME=${BRANCH_NAME}
```

I'm trying to run conditional COPY based on the value of ARG:

```
COPY if [ "$BRANCH_NAME" = "test" ] ; then --from=builder /app/robots.txt.dev ./public/robots.txt ; else --from=builder /app/robots.txt.prod ./public/robots.txt ; fi
```

but it results in an error:
When using COPY with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory and end with a / or a \dockerfile-utils(23)

What is the right syntax?

Comment: You cannot use bash scripting in `COPY` dockerfile [instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy).

Comment: You are using a multistage build. Why don't you use a `RUN` stanza to rename/copy the file to its final name inside the builder based on the environment? You can then directly `COPY --from=builder /app/robots.txt ./public/robots.txt` unconditionally in the final image